# Ng-Grid flickers grid when updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

When using ng-grid I have a server and a grid.  If I click a row data in another grid will update.  But when this happens all of the previous data disappears leaving a blank grid for 1/2 a second.  To update I am just using $http.get.

```
$http.get(afHttp.baseUrl + "/" + $scope.name + "/" + part)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
            })
        ;
```

Is there any way of fixing this?  when I add

```
var lastRoute = $route.current;
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
        $route.current = lastRoute;
    });
```

It updates fine, but then I cannot navigate to any other page, so this is no solution.  I want the update almost instant without any refresh.  Is this possible?

Comment: Is `$scope.data` what you are binding to in the grid?  You may have to expand your question and show the details of how you are configuring `ng-grid`.

Comment: @davin $scope.data is the same value that is in $scope.options.data