# Angularjs controller communicate with another controller in a different file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have one controller in file `a`, and when it does something I want it to call a function, or a controller in file `b`.  Is that possible?  I'm using ng-grid, so my reasoning for this is when `afterSelectionChange` is called in file `a`,  I want my other grid to update, and I can't merge the files or use a `$watch` function since that takes up too much time when loading a page.  I am ultimately trying to fix this problem too.  They are the same:

[Ng-Grid flickers grid when updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422136/ng-grid-flickers-grid-when-updating?noredirect=1#comment27065332_18422136)

and this is just another look at it.  If someone could answer either that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a service that is injected into both of your controllers. I've found a simple example at http://bit.ly/ZVvj1M. This should illustrate how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Having the code be in a different file doesn't really affect anything.  All of the files will be loaded into the browser when the page is loaded, so you just need a way for them to communicate.

There are a lot of ways to have 2 controllers communicate, but it is dependent on exactly what you are trying to achieve that will determine the best way to handle it.  If controller `a` and controller `b` each have a reference to the same model, you can communicate between them by updating the model.  A change in the model will immediately reflect in both controllers then.  If the models are separate (please provide an example), then a service might be a better means of communication.  And if you're doing something totally different, there might just be a better way to do it all together.

In any case, please give more specific information about exactly what you are trying to do in order to help us find the best answer.